# Error while creating trigger on table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am creating a trigger for inserting incremental ID's in my table. But while creating I am getting below error

> An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
> (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).

> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
> ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_TRIGGERCOL1 by 64 in tablespace SYSTEM

Here is my trigger query.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TGR_IPCOLO_BIL
        BEFORE INSERT ON ipcolo_ipfee_calc_bil
    for each row 
begin  
       IF INSERTING THEN 
          IF :NEW."ID" IS NULL THEN 
     select SEQ_IPCOLO_IPFEE_BIL.nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual; 
  end if; 
 END IF; 
end;
```

Comment: error code is something `ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_TRIGGERCOL1 by 64 in tablespace SYSTEM`

Comment: Looks like your SYSTEM tablespace has run out of space then; nothing to do with the trigger really, that's just what you happen to be doing when it needs space it can't find. You might be able to do some clean-up but in the short term you can increase the size. Not really a programming issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error sounds pretty bad (I never saw it before) ... *internal dictionary tables*?! What is error code? ORA-xxxxx?

---

Meanwhile, trigger can be simplified to this:

```
create or replace trigger trg_ipcolo_bil
  before insert on ipcolo_ipfee_calc_bil
  for each row
begin
  :new.id := nvl(:new.id, seq_ipolo_ipfee_bil.nextval);
end;
/
```

You don't have to check `if inserting`; what else could it be, if it fires `before insert`? Also, you don't need `select ... into` - use sequence *directly*. `nvl` makes sure you won't overwrite `id` if you provided it.

---

Also, consider using identity column instead, if your database version supports it.

Comment: error code is something `ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_TRIGGERCOL1 by 64 in tablespace SYSTEM`

Comment: Right; just Googled it. Is there any schema-level trigger which *does something* it shouldn't? Owned by SYS (or SYSTEM)? Check `select * from dba_triggers`.

Comment: getting error as ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Yes I have one trigger on another column. is it due to that

Comment: I'd rather say that user - you're currently connected to - doesn't have privileges to query DBA_TRIGGERS. But never mind that; as you commented below the question, you ran out of space so you'll have to talk to DBA.